# CSS property names auto-completion in PhpStorm

Tags: css, phpstorm, emmet

I have been using PhpStorm 2021.2 for my project but it is not auto-completing or giving suggestions for the CSS properties names. For example when I type any property like `justify-content: center;` I have to type the complete property name `justify-content` unlike in other IDEs where the IDE gives auto-complete suggestions on typing first few letters of the property.

It does not work at all for whatever property I need to use in my CSS. It is really annoying and I have to refer to the documentation again and again to get the correct property name.

I have checked the settings but I am unable to figure out the reason for such a behavior. Could you please help me find the solution for this.

Comment: 1) Please provide the code where it does not work (as minimal as possible). 2) Show a screenshot of your IDE (whole IDE window) that would show all this (the nuances may matter here). Code completion for CSS works perfectly fine for me in `.css`, `.scss` and .`less` files.

Comment: Do you have any custom plugins installed? **NativeScript** plugin, for example? It's known for breaking CSS support